# exporting X11 over ssh

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

I have a server sitting in a remote lab where I have installed openstack.I want to be able to access the xwindows on that machine so as to be able to use the http interface.

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on my machine.I have tried installing xterm on my machine but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.It seems to be a known issue but there aren't any straight work arounds.

is there some other way to export X windows to my PC ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with more information? The error you are receiving when trying to install xterm would be a good start. Are you trying to forward apps on your server to another linux PC?

Answer (score 1):

If it has X installed, you can ssh -Y hostname (to the remote host) and execute the app you want to access http on that machine with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to forward X to your computer, look into X forwarding and make sure that sshd is running on your remote lab machine, and that the ForwardX11 setting is set to Yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_conf.

However, if you only want to access HTTP through a proxy, there are better ways. One simple way that works "just like VPN" is as follows.

First install the tsocks package (temporary socks)

```
sudo apt-get install tsocks
```

Then edit `/etc/tsocks.conf` and make

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 3333
```

Now, open a terminal and type

```
ssh -ND 3333 your.server.address
```

Open another terminal (or ALT+F2) and run

```
tsocks firefox
```

Now, Firefox transmits all communication through to the SOCKS server on your computer that SSH created.  This further gets tunneled to your lab server, where it goes to the web.

It works like a charm! Alas, chromium doesn't like tsocks, but hey, Firefox works.